# Is it possible to export video playback in .glb file format in Blender?

Tags: video, 3d, export, blender, gltf

I am trying to export a 3D model which has a video as a surface. Imagine a model of a computer screen with a short video loop playing on the model's 'screen'.

I am wondering if it is possible to export in .glb (not .gltf) format and still have the video play when viewing the model?

I have tried exporting with various settings in the animation tab, but when I export and view, only the first frame of the video is being used at the surface, and it is not playing. I know .glb supports animation for rotation, location, and scale, but I wasn't able to find anything about straight up video.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on blender.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Sorry, no video support in core glTF as of yet.  Someday there may be an extension for it.